# Panel.Collapse in React-Bootstrap v1

Tags: reactjs, migration, accordion, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I am migrating from react-bootstrap v0.32.4 to v1.0.0-beta.5 and [it is written in the migration guide](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/migrating/#panel) that **Panel** has been replaced by the **Card** component.

However, I cannot find anything [in the new documentation of **Card**](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/) similar to the old **Panel.Collapse** from v0.32.

How can the following (from v0.32.4) be done with **react-bootstrap v1** by not mixing clean JSX code with plain bootstrap css classes (*e.g. accordion*)?

```
<Panel>
    <Panel.Heading>
        <Panel.Title toggle>Click Me</Panel.Title>
    </Panel.Heading>
    <Panel.Collapse>
        <Panel.Body>Collapsible Body</Panel.Body>
    </Panel.Collapse>
</Panel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took a bit of digging, but I found this link:

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/utilities/transitions/#collapse

where it appears to have extracted the Collapse logic out of Panel and put it into it's own component, managed by boolean state.